# layers is listed, no results showing

Tags: qgis

I started working with OSM layers, roads, landuse etc in QGIS. When I closed the file and reopened it, the layers are listed, but I can see any anything on the screen!

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: How did you initially load the layers into QGIS? I suspect either they are memory layers (indicated by a small memory chip icon next to the layer name), in which case they do not persist after QGIS is closed. Or, perhaps the map canvas is centered away from where the data are. Try clicking on a layer and choose `Zoom to layer(s)`